# Regex string to find numbers not starting with 91

Tags: regex

I'm trying to narrow the following regular expression:

```
/\b([0-9]{22})\b/
```

to only match 22 digit numbers that don't start with `"91"`.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What language or regular expression engine are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your regexp engine has [zero width negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), then:

```
/\b((?!91)[0-9]{22})\b/
```

`(?!91)` causes the pattern to match only if the next two characters are not 91, but does not consume those characters, leaving them to be matched by `[0-9]{22}`.

Many regexp engines also allow `\d` for decimal digits.  If yours does, then:

```
/\b((?!91)\d{22})\b/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/\b(?:[0-8][0-9]|9[02-9])[0-9]{20}\b/
```

Comment: (the negative lookahead is definitely better, if supported)

Comment: And if negative lookahead is not supported, this is the way to go.